# How to restrict application distribution to a group of users only via Apple AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm a first time iPhone application developer and I'm developing application for my client who wish to distribute this application to a group of people related to his business only, and as FREE application only. This is such an application which is not meant for general users so we definitely don't want this application is publicly listed in Apple AppStore, rather we want to distribute application to group of people privately. Just like sending them a link to download application via email or something. They click on it and application get downloaded. But in Apple I read that two programs are available like Standard Program and Enterprise Program. The standard one will list application publicly which we do not want, and enterprise programs looks compelling for enterprise users connected to MS Exchange server which we do not posses and not even wish to setup because its not needed.

Can any one help me answer following?
1. If we go with Standard program, how can we restrict application to be visible via some AppStore link ONLY and we will send that link to our users via email.
2. If we go with Enterprise Program, can we do a simple setup over our Apache+PHP+Linux environment i.e. without involving MS Exchange server.

Thanks,
Sameer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. If we go with Standard program, how can we restrict application to be
>      visible via some AppStore link ONLY
>      and we will send that link to our
>      users via email.

It is very simple: You can not. You can either manually distribute the App through AdHoc distribution (for this you will need the UDID of every single iPhone the app will be installed and afaik the the license runs out every year and needs to be renewed) or post it to the AppStore publicly but restrict access to your application by using an authentication within the App itself.

> 2. If we go with Enterprise Program, can we do a simple setup over our
>      Apache+PHP+Linux environment i.e.
>      without involving MS Exchange server.

Afaik I think this should be possible as you basically are just doing a huge AdHoc distribution, but without Exchange Server it might get a pain as you will probably also need the UDID. Yet honestly I never took any closer look at this program.

Comment: Thanks Robin. 

1. Where can I get more information on this:
"afaik the the license runs out every year and needs to be renewed".

2. Just figured out that We do have MS Exchange but only for employees, so we do not want our customers to be compelled to get connected to MS Exchange server. So we think not to go with Enterprise Program.

Your answer does help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

One way around this is to submit your application to the App Store, but put it's availability date in the future.

Then, you can create promo codes and send them to the people you'd like to be able to download your application, but it won't show up in the store.

If you do it this way, you don't need to know anybody's UDID, but you're limited to 50 people per version of your application.

Comment: WOW think like a good idea, but is it really possible? Is there any way to increase the count 50 to around 100 or 200? and also what happens when on that future date can we edit and set to more future? and whats the max future date we can set? any idea?

Comment: Also when you said submit application to the App Store, does it mean the application will need to be taken through the approval process and all by Apple?

Comment: yes, you'd need to go through the app store approval process.  You get 50 more promo codes for each new "major version" of your application.  I have no idea how long it would take Apple to get annoyed if you tried to do this for five or ten "updates".

Comment: @Sameer now it is 100.

Comment: Is availability date thesame as  release date ? just before submitting app for review there radio boxes to choose from , manually, automatically, and automatic on a particulat future date, do you mean this ? set this to future date, then generate a promo code which we can give to clients to download the app, i suppose the promocode will be a link to the app where they could download it from ? @Sameer

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the app to require a password or hot corner when first run.

Answer (score 0):

The Enterprise Program is your only viable option for a native iPhone App.  Re-read the program details. It's exactly what you want.

If you deploy your App as a Web-App, you can skip this and simply deploy on the company website, so if you don't need native iPhone options, this might also be a viable way to deploy your program.

-t

Comment: yes our application is native app not web app. Enterprise Program does look good to me too, but have complexities and the major concern is it seems that there is a competition that end user have to be connected to MS Exchange server, which seems good idea if app is distributed to employees, but in my case, end users are not employees rather a group of people in our customer base.

Comment: There is no requirement for MS Exchange. The Enterprise Development Program includes information on how to connect to an Exchange Server for data exchange since many enterprise customers have this need. The App is not distributed through an MS Exchange server. If your target company does not have 500 employees however, it doesn't qualify for the program anyway.

Your option appears to be the App Store as a free App with user authentication using your own internal scheme for your customers. Anyone else who downloads the App simply will not be able to connect to your server...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to qualify for the Enterprise Program: you'll need a minimum number of employees and a DUNS number. Read the [Enrollment document](http://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/enrollment/) for more information. Your situation (as described) does not sound like it qualifies.

Comment: Thanks Alex! But its not a problem now, we do have MS Exchange and employee limits criteria fulfilled. But we are not going to use this application for internal purpose, rather we've a group of users who shall be using our applications. MS Exchange doesn't look like a good place to host application as it puts lot of complexities in the distribution mechanism. What do you suggest? Enterprise or Standard program?

Answer (score 0):

Another mechanism is to submit your app to App Store as an "Unlisted App."  It will not be found in any searches and can only be seen and downloaded by a direct link to your app on the App Store.  Since anyone with that link can download your app, it's best to have a password implemented within the app as well.  Here is the Apple documentation on this. https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/