# How do you create a "promo code" for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

How you do you "create promo codes" for an app as given in the answer by David Maymudes (below question link)? Is there an iOS UI for it?

[How to restrict application distribution to a group of users only via Apple AppStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104922/how-to-restrict-application-distribution-to-a-group-of-users-only-via-apple-appst/3738582#3738582)

Comment: Note that promo codes are only good for the US App Store currently.

Comment: Ok good to know, i'm in Canada. Thanks

Comment: [Postum duplicate with screenshots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447400/why-cant-i-request-promo-codes-for-my-ios-app).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to itunesconnect.apple.com. On the front page is a link to "Request Promotional Codes".

Comment: Every once in a while, Apple changes the iTunesConnect site.  As of this writing, the process is: go to itunesConnect.apple.com, select *Manage Your Apps*, select your app, select *View Details*, then use the *Promo Codes* button on the top-right of that page.

Comment: @Olie - How can i do it for the update of my application?
I don't want to release the app to the public  - just want to send it for some reviewers...

My app current state is Ready for sale and the promo codes is available for it.
The update is currently pending developer release (and i'm afraid that pressing on the "Release this app" button will get it publically availbale. - so can i create promo codes for the update?

Comment: @ItayLevin What happend? Did you press "Release this app"?

Answer (score 1):

You register as a developer and do it through "iTunes Connect", option "Request Promotional Codes"