# Why can't I request promo codes for my iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, promotion-code

Apple's FAQ states this:

> **Why don't I see a Promo Codes button for my app?**
>    Only iTunes Connect users with the Legal role are able to access the Promo Codes button and make requests for promo codes.
>
> If you are logged in to an iTunes connect account with the Legal role, and the Promo Codes button for your app is still not appearing, the app may not be approved. The Promo Codes button will only be displayed for approved apps with the status Ready for Sale.

The thing is that all these criteria are met, and yet I don't see the Promo Codes button:

- I'm using the iTunes Connect user account that has the *Legal* role.
- The app has been approved. It's [available in App Stores](http://itunes.apple.com/app/audiopad/id534105189?mt=8) worldwide.

**How do I get this Promo Codes button?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought the button would be among these (marked in red) but I found it in the version details (green arrow):

[image]

... And there it is:
[image]

Now I feel silly, but smarter!

Comment: I think you have to wait at least 2 days before you can accept your own answer.

Comment: 2 days have passed now... Quite a long time ago!